# Customizing Qt Docking behavior

Tags: qt, panel, docking, dockpanel, qdockwidget

I'm using Qt 4.8 to build an application, and am finding the default docking support in Qt to be quite restrictive for my purposes. Does anyone have any experience customizing the Qt docking behavior?

Instead of being constrained to the four dock widget areas, I would like to extend the docking capability to work similar to Photoshop/Flash or even Visual Studio - where any edge of the main window or another panel can be used for panel layout? From what I can tell, I am forced to re-implement QMainWindow to add my own logic. Is this assessment correct?

Comment: Since posting this question, I (and my team) have implemented a nice docking system on top of the public Qt API. I'm unable to share code, but know that it is possible. It's not a simple process however, and expect to put in a lot of work depending on your functional requirements.